# Blackberry Playbook WebWorks How to make a textfield open a different virtual keyboard?

Tags: blackberry, textfield, blackberry-playbook, virtual-keyboard

I'm developing a WebWorks application for the Blackberry Playbook. This page in their documentation says

> You can display a specific type of virtual keyboard, depending on the
>   type of input that is required. In addition to the default keyboard,
>   you can choose from a selection of keyboards, such as a keyboard
>   designed for typing in an email or a keyboard designed for typing in a
>   browser.

https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_best_practices/ui_components_tablet_microsites_1877108_11.html

However, I can't find any documentation on how to actually DO that. I have some fields for entering an email address, so I'd like to give the user an email focused keyboard.

This is a WebWorks app, not Flash. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those special keyboard layouts are determined the `type` attribute of HTML5 `<input>` tags.  Here are some of the "special" types defined in the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#states-of-the-type-attribute):

> - tel
> - url
> - email
> - number

When selected, the respective keyboard layout will appear for you.

Blackberry has also their own document where they list [all possible `<input>` types available under WebWorks](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/html_input_types_1247751_11.html).

Comment: what about alpha numeric?  currently it only shows alpha and i have to switch to numeric, which is a pain for postal codes and airline confirmation numbers